# Is the genus of biholomorphic Riemann surfaces the same?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology

Is the statement above true for $X \cong_{bihol} Y$? I would say yes, since I can transform any holomorphic function on a open set in $X$ to one in $Y$ and vice versa.

Comment: Your second sentence suggests you meant the [geometric genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Algebraic_geometry) defined as the dimension of the vector space of holomorphic 1-forms, so you need to inject those 1-forms from X to Y

Comment: Yes, I meant $g:= dim H^1(X, \mathcal{O})$. Why 1-forms?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite get it yet, $\mathcal{O}$ is the sheaf of holomorphic functions, why do I need to look at 1-forms at all?

Comment: Fix some $x_0\in X$, let $R_X$ be the space of functions analytic around $x_0$ having an analytic continuation over any curve $\in X$ (it is the same as the analytic functions on the universal cover). Let $O_X$ be the globally analytic functions on $X$, and $S_X$ those $\in R_X$ whose continuation over any closed loop differs by some element of $O_X$, and $\Omega_X$ the analytic 1-forms. If $X$ is a compact Riemann surface then $O_X$ is just the constant functions and $f\mapsto df$ is an isomorphism $H^1(X,O)=S_X/O_X\to\Omega_X$. If $X,Y$ are biholomorphic those things stay the same on $Y$

Comment: Now I see that in your first comment you wrote "vector space of holomorphic one forms", I kind of overread that but that's not my definition of genus, its the dimension of the first cohomology group for the golomorphic functions (not 1- forms)

Comment: And anything unclear ? Then for $f \in H^1(X,O)$ and a closed loop $\gamma \in \pi_1(X)$ let $f(\gamma)$ be the increment of $f$ along $\gamma$, then $\gamma \mapsto \Re(f(\gamma))$ is a character $\pi_1(X) \to \mathbb{R}$, and the main theorem is that the map $H^1(X,O) \to Hom(\pi_1(X), \mathbb{R})$ is surjective ie. $g$ is also the number of holes

Comment: ok then I think I maybe don't have the required knowledge to understand your explanation, I don't know what character means here or the main theorem..

Comment: I was thinking there is an easier way but there isn't? I just don't understand why it's taken for granted then in my lecture..

Answer (score 0):

Biholomorphic $\implies$ homeomorphic...